# javascript float or double for handling currency/money value

Tags: javascript, floating-point, double, currency

Which type to use (float or double) for handling currency/money? At the moment I am using float for handling currency/money. I searched through the net, but found nothing. I know this is a question that includes debate which is not allowed, but I need some explanation for me to decide.

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, use a decimal number type for currency, so that you have exact representation of numbers like 0.1. If you have to use a binary floating point type, use 64-bit not 32-bit. 64-bit can represent the US national debt to the nearest cent. 32-bit cannot represent a business bank account exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[There is only one type of number in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp).
So you don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point numbers, i.e. double.

See the following links for more information:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html

You don't have a choice in regard to the way your numbers are stored.